# How to add role to user while saving user?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two objects having relation as user-->role (one user to many role). Now i am trying to save this user, here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
<br>
<div class="panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">{{addOrUpdateLabel}}</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form role="form" class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Enter Email</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" ng-disabled="disableEmailField"></input>
                <p class="help-block"></p> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Enter Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name"></input>
                <p class="help-block"></p> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Enter Contact Number</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.contact"></input>
                <p class="help-block"></p> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Add Role to User</label><br>
                <select ng-model="currentRole" ng-options="r for r in rolesArray" style="width:380px; height:30px;">
                <option value="">Select role</option></select>
                <p class="help-block"></p> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-hide="hidePasswordField">
                <label for="">Enter Password</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password"></input>
                <p class="help-block"></p> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-click="save(user)" ng-show="showAddButton">Save</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-click="update(user)" ng-show="showUpdateButton">Update</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
                <a href="/users/all"><button class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button></a>
            </div>                      
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have rolesArray which contains some predefined roles as:

```
$scope.rolesArray = ["USER", "ADMIN", "DBA"];
```

1. my problem is how to add role (my ng-model="currentRole") to user model. my user model looks like:
   **{"id":"1","username":"xyz@abc.com","password":"******", "roles":{"id":"1", "rolename":"USER"}}**

Answer (score -1):

Add the selected roles to the `user` object in the `save` method. Although the `currentRole` doesn't contain id's for the role so not sure how to get those.

```
public save(user): void {
  angular.forEach(this.currentRole, (role)=> {
    user.roles.push({id: role.id, rolename: role.name});
  }
}
```